# 16x2 LCD Display Got Error Cause by External Current

Tags: arduino, lcd

[image]

As shown in the image above

- the 16x2 LCD display is controlled by Arduino.
- Relay and LCD both connected to +5V of Arduino

The LCD got an erroneous symbols display whenever I pug/unplug the relay to the 220Vac supply.

I guess I need to add a component in between the positive line of LCD and RELAY, but I don't know what it is. Does capacitor will help?

Comment: How is the Arduino connected to the mains ? Please tell me there is an opto-isolator in between. Frankly I'm more concerned with the safety of the circuit than the LCD errors. There isn't sufficient detail in the question. Perhaps, why do you need an apparatus could help us better to give an answer.

Comment: The relay i used is electromagnetic. The 220Vac supply on the other side of the relay doesn't passed to Arduino, so the whole system is safe.

Comment: Ok . Sorry for my rant .is the right side (mains) connected when you remove the relay ?

Comment: Relay is fixedly attached on Arduino, when you unplug the relay to the mains, the mains absolutely not connected to the Arduino.